# Angular don't show same user as currently shown

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

So I need some help showing a list of users that I get from an API call... each user has an unique ID but on the JSON that I get from the API the first user is always the same as currently opened...

**So example...** my url is [www.domain.com/user/12345](http://www.domain.com/user/12345) for this user I get a list of related users but the first user on that list is that same user with this 12345 ID... how do I skip the user with the same ID as currently opened so that on the list of those similar users that user wouldn't appear?

Here is the service how I'm getting the data from the API:

```
  getCustomerSimilar(id:number): Observable<CustomerSimilar> {
    return this.httpClient.get<CustomerSimilar>(`${environment.apiUrl}customer/${id}/similar`)
  }
```

Here is the .ts file how I get the users from API:

```
  getCustomerSimilar() {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.customerService.getCustomerSimilar(id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.similarClients = data.data;
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }
```

Here is the JSON response I get:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "Name Lastname",
    },
    {
        "id": "12346",
        "name": "Something Lastname",
    },
    {
        "id": "12347",
        "name": "Something Something",
    }
 ]
```

Here is my model

```
export interface CustomerSimilar {
  data: [
    {
      id: number;
      name: string;
    }
  ]
}
```

here is the HTML template so show the users:

```
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let podobna of similarClients" class="mat-list-item-focus" routerLink="/customers/{{podobna.id}}" role="navigation">
          <mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined" matListItemIcon>account_circle</mat-icon>
          <div matListItemTitle class="similar-customer-name">{{podobna.name}}</div>
          <div matListItemLine class="similar-customer-ddv" *ngIf="podobna.vat_number">VAT: {{podobna.vat_number}}</div>
          <div matListItemLine class="similar-customer-id">ID: {{podobna.id}}</div>
          <div matListItemLine class="similar-customer-email" *ngIf="podobna.email">Email: {{podobna.email}}</div>
        </mat-list-item>
```

Comment: Can you share the response you get and what you want as a response json?

Comment: @SelakaN I have added the response... As you can see the first user has ID 12345.. if I am on this user I just want to see the next two users from that response... but my code also shows the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the response data you receive from the service at component level based on the id once you receive the response inside the subscribe method in the component `getCustomerSimilar()` method and assign it to the `this.similarClients` array.

> Read more on array filter [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

**Refer to the below code for reference :**

```
     getCustomerSimilar() {
        const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
        this.customerService.getCustomerSimilar(id).subscribe(
          data => {
            data.data = data?.data?.filter(function (el) {
            return el.id != id ;
           }
        );
       this.similarClients =data;
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }
```

**Refer the plain javascript working sample below :**

```js
var arr ={
   "data": [
    {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "Name Lastname"
    },
    {
        "id": "12346",
        "name": "Something Lastname"
    },
    {
        "id": "12347",
        "name": "Something Something"
    }
  ]
 }

const id = 12345;
 
arr.data = arr?.data?.filter(function (el) {
    return el.id != id ;
});

console.log(arr);
```

And your model should be corrected as :

```
export interface ResultObject {
    data: items[];
}

export interface Items {
    id:   string;
    name: string;
}
```

Comment: I am now getting the error: Type '{ id: number; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '[{id: number; name: string;}]'.

Comment: Check the updated answer..  Appreciate if you can mark it as a correct answer and give a upvote.. : )

Comment: Hey I have added the code of my service to my question

Comment: Keep the service as it is. Only update the component code `getCustomerSimilar()` method. Highly Appreciate if you can mark it as a correct answer and give vote to it.

Comment: Your code gives this error now:  The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access. data?.data = data?.data?.filter(function (el) {

Comment: Ive updated answer refer the latest plz

Comment: I am now back at this error: I am now getting the error: Type '{ id: number; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '[{id: number; name: string;}]'

Comment: Thats a `type` error which specific to you.  You can resolve it via using type `any` provided answer based on the model you shared in your question. which is followed by a working sample.

Comment: Also this is in the error: Type 'CustomerSimilar' is not assignable to type '[{id: number; name: string;}]'

Comment: I have aded my type CustomerSimilar definition to my question... hope you can have a look now

Comment: This anwser doesent work

Comment: You Json model is wrong. Corrected model is attached in answer have look.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter other than the id of that user like that

```
getCustomerSimilar() {
  const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  this.customerService.getCustomerSimilar(id)
  .pipe(
    map(response => response.data),
    map(users => users.filters(user => user.id != id))
  )
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.similarClients = data;
    },
    error => {
      console.log('Error', error);
    });
}
```

import `map` from `rxjs`